# Rotated Text in Table Extending into Rows in Lyx

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, formatting, lyx

I'm trying to create a table with some rotated text in it, but the rotated text is extending into the rows below the cell, as shown here:

[image]

Here is what my screen looks like in Lyx:

[image]

I've tried using multirow, multicolumn, and rotatetext to no avail. Right now the cells in the left-most column are rotated by using the *`Rotate cell by 90`* function in Lyx.

Comment: Well, a solution depends on the text to be rotated. You can increase the rows height, or rotate some multiline `\parbox` (easy to do with the `makecell` package).

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks for your comment. My text is roughly the same width as that shown in the figures above. So any commands you have should be helpful. Please let me know.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example. The solutions can be very specific, or be a blend of several techniques.

Comment: @Bernard, my example is posted in my question. I put it there to help and show what I've done. I'm using Lyx.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way. I use the `makecell` and `rotating` packages, plus `hhline` (the ordinary horizontal last line and vertical first line do not join well) and `caption` (for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, array, rotating, multirow}
\ usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\footnotesize\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|l*{3}{|X}|}
\cline{3-5}
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \thead{Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum} & \thead{Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum} & \thead{Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum}\\
\cline{2-5}
\multirowcell{9}[-2pt]{ \rotatebox{90}{{Lorem Ipsum}}} & Lorem Ipsum & & & \\
\cline{2-5}
 & Lorem Ipsum & & & \\
\cline{2-5}
 & Lorem Ipsum & & & \\
\cline{2-5}
 & Lorem Ipsum & & & \\
\cline{2-5}
 & Lorem Ipsum & & & \\
\cline{2-5} & Lorem Ipsum & & & \\
\hhline{~|----|}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's insane to me that no one has written a basic table generation package that can center text properly like is done in Excel. I'm sure the problem isn't trivial, but it boggles my mind this doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you mean centre a rotated text in a table? The problem comes mainly from `multirow`, which very often requires some manual adjustment.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I had to do in my code eventually, I had to use a bunch of manual adjustment.  I had to use these commands get the rotated text on two lines and the ~ symbol for spacing \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Lorem Ipsum ~~~} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Lorem Ipsum Ipsum ~~~}